In Gitlab CI variables not available in before_script when setup using workflow rules
I'm having an issue where variables set in the workflow rules in the Gitlab CI are not available when calling the before_script. Only after the before_script is ran, I see the variables when calling 'env'. When I hardcode the variable as a variable in the stage, the variable is available in the before_script as well.
Any advice would be appreciated :)
Steps to reproduce

Create a.gitlab-ci.yml file with workflow rules:

# Set the variables using workflow rules, so I can have different variables for different branches
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        ACCOUNT: $PRD_ACCOUNT_ID
        ENV: "prd"
        ROLE_ARN: "arn:aws:iam::${PRD_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/role-${ENV}-euc1-${PRD_ACCOUNT_ID}"
        AWS_ENV_NAME: "prd-aws"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"
      variables:
        ACCOUNT: $NPE_ACCOUNT_ID
        ENV: "npe"
        TF_ROLE_ARN: "arn:aws:iam::${NPE_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/role-${ENV}-euc1-${NPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"
        AWS_ENV_NAME: "npe-aws"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "develop"
      variables:
        ACCOUNT: $NPE_ACCOUNT_ID
        ENV: "npe"
        TF_ROLE_ARN: "arn:aws:iam::${NPE_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/role-${ENV}-euc1-${NPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"
        AWS_ENV_NAME: "npe-aws"
      when: always
    - when: always

# Here the ROLE_ARN is set, which is being used to download a terraform module from gitlab
.init:
  before_script:
    - ${AWS_PROFILE}]\nrole_arn=${ROLE_ARN}

terraform validate:
  extends:
    - .tf:init # in the extends a before_script is called which needs the ROLE_ARN
  stage: Validate
  script:
    - env # here I see the var is there, but only AFTER the before_script
    - ./cicd_scripts/init.sh
    - terraform -chdir=${TF_ROOT} validate
  rules:
    # only run on feature branches
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual

Current bug behavior:
when the Validate stage is run with the above configuration, it fails because it can't find the ROLE_ARN. If I hardcode the ROLE_ARN as a variable in the stage, it does work:
# This DOES work but means I need to hardcode the role, which I don't want
terraform validate:
  extends:
    - .tf:init # in the extends a before_script is called which needs the ROLE_ARN
  stage: Validate
  variables:
    ROLE_ARN: "arn:aws:iam::123:role/role-npe-euc1-123"
  script:
    - ./cicd_scripts/init.sh
    - terraform -chdir=${TF_ROOT} validate
  rules:
    # only run on feature branches
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual

What do I need to change in order for the variables set in the workflow, to be available as a variable in each stage and the before_script? Since the workflow rules are set globally, I would expect the variables be available in each stage and the before_script.
If I add the variable in the stage like so:
# This DOES work but means I need to hardcode the role, which I don't want
terraform validate:
  extends:
    - .tf:init # in the extends a before_script is called which needs the ROLE_ARN
  stage: Validate
  variables:
    ROLE_ARN: $ROLE_ARN (or ${ROLE_ARN} or "${ROLE_ARN}")
  script:
    - ./cicd_scripts/init.sh
    - terraform -chdir=${TF_ROOT} validate
  rules:
    # only run on feature branches
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual

It also does not work. Then it sees the value as hardcoded $ROLE_ARN.
